# Remove password policy on a personal machine

Tags: security, password

When I left my previous organization I bought a new Mac, and migrated content from my work machine to my personal machine. The downside is some of the JAMF policies carried over. One of those was the password policy.

When I went to change my password from a very secure but ridiculously long passphrase to something shorter, I was prevented by the inherited password policy, which instructed me to contact "my domain administrator". (Hey, that's now me!)

**Question: How do I remove password policy enforcement from a personal machine?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Password policy is controlled by the Terminal command `pwpolicy`.

To remove password policies from all users on the machine, open Terminal.app and run:

```shell
pwpolicy -clearaccountpolicies
```

To remove password policies from only a single user, open Terminal.app and run:

```shell
pwpolicy -u <user_name> -clearaccountpolicies
```

You can `man pwpolicy` to lean more about how to use it.

*This post made possible by the [example policy script from Jeff Holland](https://community.jamf.com/t5/jamf-pro/user-password-policies-on-non-ad-machines/m-p/107802) in the JAMF forums.*